How configure Nginx to retain location path when accessing service via Nginx URL
I have one of many microsites that is hosted on a remote backend server as https://remote-server.mydomain.com/pdf
I'm trying to publish via Nginx proxy on a different location to keep things centralized with following config.
/etc/nginx/conf.d/backends.conf

upstream pdf-dev {
    zone pdf-dev-service 256k;
    server https://remote-server.mydomain.com;
}

/etc/nginx/conf.d/pdf.conf

location /dev/pdf {
    proxy_pass https://pdf-dev/pdf;

}

Nginx can be reached via https://gateway.mydomain.com
When I hit the url https://gateway.mydomain.com/dev/pdf I get the microsite.
But then, the minute I hit the links inside the microsite, I'm getting served the subsequent URLs dropping 'dev' part in the location. Like, if I click on 'about' in the loaded page, Nginx serves it as https://gateway.mydomain.com/pdf/about instead of https://gateway.mydomain.com/dev/pdf/about
Any way to retain the path /dev/pdf. Because we're thinking of leveraging nginx to publish microsites from other environments like PAT and PROD.
I tried different config options available in different stack posts with no help.

Just remove the /pdf from the proxy_pass line. It'll then pass the whole thing

This is at the very base of nginx proxy_pass directive and i strongly believe you should have used at least a minute of your time to 'google' it at least once...
That being said:
As per this nginx documentation page;

IF the address of the proxied server is followed by a URI and if the URI is specified along with the address, it replaces the part of the request URI that matches the location parameter. If the address is specified without a URI, or it is not possible to determine the part of URI to be replaced, the full request URI is passed (possibly, modified).

Better yet, according to this documentation page, again
A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
    location /name/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
    }

If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:
    location /some/path/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
    }

